# Python keyword to access class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, class-variables

Consider the following  class in Python 3:

```
class Foo(AnotherClass):
    id_counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = Foo.id_counter
        Foo.id_counter += 1
```

Is there a keyword (similar to Python's `super` in this case) that can be used to access class variables in place of putting the class name `Foo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type(self)` or `self.__class__` will return the actual class of `self`, which might be a subclass of `Foo` or `Foo`:

```
class Foo(AnotherClass):
    id_counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = type(self).id_counter
        type(self).id_counter += 1
```

Comment: you could also use `type(self)` instead of `self.__class__` if you prefer... After all, you'd use `len(self)` instead of `self.__len__()` wouldn't you?   :-P

Comment: Very smart, @mgilson.  Sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: @SimonT -- In my own code, I frequently use `self.__class__` mainly because it behaves properly on python2.x when you could potentially be dealing with old-style classes (*Oh the horror!*).

Comment: @mgilson: `type()` is sometimes too literal.`type(weakref.proxy(x))` is `weakproxy`, whereas `weakref.proxy(x).__class__` is `x.__class__`.

Comment: @eryksun -- Fair point.  `instance.__class__` *is* writable, so you can't trust it to be 100% accurate (sometimes for the better as is the case of `weakproxy`).

Comment: @mgilson, if setting `x.__class__` succeeds, then `type(x)` will agree. For a heap type reassignment to work in CPython, the types need to have the same `tp_dealloc` and `tp_free`, and the object layout has to be compatible (actually even compatible layouts get rejected, since it errs on the side of caution).